Calculate the change of basis matrix for a linear map on polynomials
I am reading this paper and I am apparently not understanding what the matrix representation of a linear operator means. I give the full example here, the context of the paper does not matter.
Consider the space of all polynomials up to degree 2 on $\mathbb{R}$, denoted by $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, the functions $f_0(x) = \epsilon^{-1}$, $f_1(x) = \epsilon^{-1} x$ and $f_2(x) = \epsilon^{-1} x^2$ form a basis of $\mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$. Now I have the linear map $H_t: \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ for fixed $t \geq 0$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
H_tf(x) = (\theta t - x) f'(x) + \frac12 f''(x).
$$
My understanding is that the matrix representation of this map is the matrix $(h_{ij})_{i,j=0,1,2}$ such that for all $j = 0,1,2$ it holds
$$
H_t f_j = \sum_{i=0}^2 h_{ij} f_i,
$$
i.e. I look at what the map $H_t$ does to a basis element and represent it again in my basis $f_0,f_1,f_2$. Concretely I calculate:
$$
H_tf_0(x) = 0 = 0 f_0 + 0 f_1 + 0 f_2 \\
H_tf_1(x) = (\theta t - x) \epsilon^{-1} = \theta t f_0 + (-1) f_1 \\
H_tf_2(x) = (\theta t - x) 2\epsilon^{-1} x + \epsilon^{-1}= f_0 + 2\theta t f_1 + (-2) f_2\\
$$
Hence, I have the matrix representation
$$
\mathbf{H}_t=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \theta t & 1\\
0 & -1 & 2\theta t \\
0 & 0 &  - 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
However, the authors in the paper write that the matrix representation is given by
$$
\mathbf{H}_t= \epsilon
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \theta t & 1\\
0 & -1 & 2\theta t \\
0 & 0 &  - 2
\end{pmatrix},
$$
i.e. an additional factor of $\epsilon$.
Question: What am I not understanding or doing wrong? Or do I have a different understanding of what a change of basis means?
Thanks in advance!

I see no error in your computations.

You understand correctly how a linear operator is represented by a matrix.
It looks like you've discovered a typo! In fact, since your basis is a scalar multiple of the standard monomial basis
$$
\{1, x, x^2\}
$$
the matrix would be the same
$$
\mathbf{H}_t =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \theta t & 1\\
0 & -1 & 2\theta t \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
in that basis as well. The change-of-basis matrix between your basis and the monomial basis is the scalar $\epsilon^{-1}I$ which commutes with any matrix, so this offers an alternative way to calculate this matrix:
$$
(\epsilon^{-1}I)^{-1} \, \mathbf{H}_t \, (\epsilon^{-1}I) 
= \mathbf{H}_t.
$$
The only way that the matrix $\epsilon \mathbf{H}_t$ would represent this operator is if we choose your basis in the source and the monomial basis in the target. But this is highly unusual since the the source and target are the same space.

Thank you very much! I edit my post with a follow up question.

Please write a new question, in which you can link this question for context.

Just read your comment, I write a new question now.

Removed my edit and made a new post, here.
